# C++ - statement cannot resolve address for overloaded function

Tags: c++, function, resolve

When I types the following as a stand-alone line:

`std::endl;`

I got the following error:

`statement cannot resolve address for overloaded function`

Why is that? Cannot I write `std::endl;` as a stand-alone line?

Thanks.

Comment: Which stream's line would it end?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`std::endl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) is a function template.  Normally, it's used as an argument to the insertion operator `<<`. In that case, the `operator<<` of the stream in question will be defined as e.g. `ostream& operator<< (  ostream& (*f)( ostream& ) )`.  The type of the argument of `f` is defined, so the compiler will then know the exact overload of the function.

It's comparable to this:

```
void f( int ){}
void f( double ) {}
void g( int ) {}
template<typename T> void ft(T){}

int main(){
  f; // ambiguous
  g; // unambiguous
  ft; // function template of unknown type...
}
```

But you can resolve the ambiguity by some type hints:

```
void takes_f_int( void (*f)(int) ){}

takes_f_int( f ); // will resolve to f(int) because of `takes_f_int` signature
(void (*)(int)) f; // selects the right f explicitly 
(void (*)(int)) ft; // selects the right ft explicitly
```

That's what happens normally with `std::endl` when supplied as an argument to `operator <<`: there is a definition of the function

```
 typedef (ostream& (*f)( ostream& ) ostream_function;
 ostream& operator<<( ostream&, ostream_function )
```

And this will enable the compiler the choose the right overload of `std::endl` when supplied to e.g. `std::cout << std::endl;`.

Nice question!

Comment: `std::endl` is a single function template, not a function or set of overloaded functions. If it were just a single function the statement `std::endl;` would be fine (if pointless).

Comment: @Charles Bailey: corrected for that; would it change the reasoning a lot?   I don't think so.  The ambiguity is resolved using the `operator <<` in casu.

Comment: It makes the reasoning more applicable, if anything.

Comment: Your obfuscating the real answer. It just needs a parameter.

Comment: @Martin York: my guess was OP wanted to know "what did the compiler mean", not "how should I use `std::endl`".  I didn't know, either.  Indeed, `std::endl` _is_ a function, as stated clearly in this and other answers, but the interesting thing is I never needed to ask  myself that - it just worked.  In the solitary, nonsensical expression `std::endl;`, the compiler suddenly didn't have a way to know what to do.  I think it's a very good question, and I think I learned something by answering it, and that OP learned something by reading it.

Comment: @Martin York: ... and you must admit that most people never thought about giving `std::endl` a parameter.

Comment: Very interesting! Especially because it's the same for std::flush, which I didn't expect to use the << operator.

Answer (score 4):

The most *likely* reason I can think of is that it's declaration is:

```
ostream& endl ( ostream& os );
```

In other words, without being part of a `<<` operation, there's no `os` that can be inferred. I'm pretty certain this is the case since the line:

```
std::endl (std::cout);
```

compiles just fine.

My question to you is: why would you *want* to do this?

I know for a fact that `7;` is a perfectly valid statement in C but you don't see that kind of rubbish polluting my code :-)

Comment: I made it that way for the seek of readability, and that tells a newline has been inserted after some statement. But, seems it is invalid to write it the way I did. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

std::endl is a manipulator. It's actually a function that is called by the a version of the << operator on a stream.

```
std::cout << std::endl
// would call 
std::endl(std::cout).
```

Answer (score 4):

`std::endl` is a function template. If you use it in a context where the template argument cannot be uniquely determined you have to disambiguate which specialization you mean. For example you can use an explicit cast or assign it to a variable of the correct type.

e.g.

```
#include <ostream>

int main()
{
    // This statement has no effect:
    static_cast<std::ostream&(*)(std::ostream&)>( std::endl );

    std::ostream&(*fp)(std::ostream&) = std::endl;
}
```

Usually, you just use it in a context where the template argument is deduced automatically.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::endl( std::cout );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/endl/

You can't have `std::endl` by itself because it requires a `basic_ostream` as a type of parameter. It's the way it is defined.

It's like trying to call `my_func()` when the function is defined as `void my_func(int n)`

Answer (score 2):

endl is a function that takes a parameter. See [std::endl on cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/endl/)

```
// This works.
std::endl(std::cout);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `std::endl` terminates a line and flushes the buffer. So it should be connected the stream like `cout` or similar.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
class student{

      private: 
           string coursecode;
           int number,total;
      public:
           void getcourse(void);
           void getnumber(void);
           void show(void);
      };

        void  student ::getcourse(){

              cout<<"pleas enter the course code\n";
              cin>>coursecode;

              }


        void  student::getnumber(){

                     cout<<"pleas enter the number \n";
                     cin>>number;

                     }
                void  student::show(){

                             cout<<"coursecode is\t\t"<<coursecode<<"\t\t and number is "<<number<<"\n";

                             } 
                             int main()
                             {

                                   student s;

                                  s.getcourse();
                                   s.getnumber(); 
                                   s.show();
                                   system("pause");









                                   }
```