# Overloading T and vector<T>

Tags: c++

I have a static method `ToString(T)` and an overload `ToString(vector<T>)`. This works for normal use, but not with boost bind. See my example code:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

class MetaData
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    static std::string ToString(T inValue)
    {
        return boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(inValue);
    }

    template<typename T>
    static std::string ToString(const std::vector<T> & inValues)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        for (typename std::vector<T>::size_type idx = 0; idx < inValues.size(); ++idx)
        {
            if (idx != 0)
            {
                ss << ", ";
            }
            ss << inValues[idx];
        }
        return ss.str();
    }

    int getInt() { return 42; }

    std::vector<int> getIntVector()
    {
        std::vector<int> result;
        result.push_back(1);
        result.push_back(2);
        result.push_back(3);
        return result;
    }

    void test();
};

void MetaData::test()
{
    boost::function< std::string() > foo;

    // Ok
    foo = boost::bind(&ToString<int>, boost::bind(&MetaData::getInt, this));
    std::cout << foo() << std::endl;

    // Compiler errors
    foo = boost::bind(&ToString<int>, boost::bind(&MetaData::getIntVector, this));
    std::cout << foo() << std::endl;

    // Ok
    std::cout << ToString<int>(getIntVector()) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    MetaData metaData;
    metaData.test();
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit**
These are the compiler errors I'm getting:

```
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp: In member function ‘R boost::_bi::list1<A1>::operator()(boost::_bi::type<R>, F&, A&, long int) [with R = std::basic_string<char>, F = std::basic_string<char> (*)(int), A = boost::_bi::list0, A1 = boost::_bi::bind_t<std::vector<int>, boost::_mfi::mf0<std::vector<int>, MetaData>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<MetaData*> > >]’:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:20:59:   instantiated from ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::operator()() [with R = std::basic_string<char>, F = std::basic_string<char> (*)(int), L = boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::bind_t<std::vector<int>, boost::_mfi::mf0<std::vector<int>, MetaData>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<MetaData*> > > >, boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type = std::basic_string<char>]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:132:42:   instantiated from ‘static R boost::detail::function::function_obj_invoker0<FunctionObj, R>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&) [with FunctionObj = boost::_bi::bind_t<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> (*)(int), boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::bind_t<std::vector<int>, boost::_mfi::mf0<std::vector<int>, MetaData>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<MetaData*> > > > >, R = std::basic_string<char>]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:913:60:   instantiated from ‘void boost::function0<R>::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> (*)(int), boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::bind_t<std::vector<int>, boost::_mfi::mf0<std::vector<int>, MetaData>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<MetaData*> > > > >, R = std::basic_string<char>]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:722:7:   instantiated from ‘boost::function0<R>::function0(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> (*)(int), boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::bind_t<std::vector<int>, boost::_mfi::mf0<std::vector<int>, MetaData>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<MetaData*> > > > >, R = std::basic_string<char>, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1064:16:   instantiated from ‘boost::function<R()>::function(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> (*)(int), boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::bind_t<std::vector<int>, boost::_mfi::mf0<std::vector<int>, MetaData>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<MetaData*> > > > >, R = std::basic_string<char>, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1105:5:   instantiated from ‘typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, boost::function<R()>&>::type boost::function<R()>::operator=(Functor) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> (*)(int), boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::bind_t<std::vector<int>, boost::_mfi::mf0<std::vector<int>, MetaData>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<MetaData*> > > > >, R = std::basic_string<char>, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, boost::function<R()>&>::type = boost::function<std::basic_string<char>()>&]’
main.cpp:55:81:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:243:60: error: cannot convert ‘boost::_bi::result_traits<std::vector<int>, boost::_mfi::mf0<std::vector<int>, MetaData> >::type’ to ‘int’ in argument passing
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Turn `ToString` into a functor and overload `operator()` for your vector. Then you can just pass it to bind via `bind(ToString(), ....)` and all will be well (bind can resolve the template internally if you pass the functor, but not if you just take a function pointer).

Like this:

```
struct ToString
{
    template<typename T>
    std::string operator()(T inValue) const
    {
        return boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(inValue);
    }

    template<typename T>
    std::string operator()(const std::vector<T> & inValues) const
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        for (typename std::vector<T>::size_type idx = 0; idx < inValues.size(); ++idx)
        {
            if (idx != 0)
            {
                ss << ", ";
            }
            ss << inValues[idx];
        }
        return ss.str();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`&ToString<int>` is ambiguous at that point. You should resolve it explicitly by casting it to the signature of the specific function you want. See this related question: [C++ - statement cannot resolve address for overloaded function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842901/c-statement-cannot-resolve-address-for-overloaded-function)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you take the address of `ToString` in the second case, the compiler still thinks you mean the first version (`int`) instead of the `vector` version. Then when the bind tries to check the parameter/return type match, it doesn't agree.

Are you able to use a different function name to disambiguate? You can always create an inline wrapper `ToString(vector)` that calls through to the differently named helper for use when you're explicitly calling it out (not with bind).

You can also cast the `ToString` function address to the correct overload (as shown in another answer) but this may or may not be a clearer solution.

Answer (score 0):

With this:

```
foo = boost::bind(&ToString<int>, boost::bind(&MetaData::getIntVector, this));
```

you're explicitly telling the compiler to use the `<int>` version of `ToString`, even though you're trying to pass it a vector.  Try this:

```
foo = boost::bind(&ToString<std::vector<int> >, boost::bind(&MetaData::getIntVector, this));
```

Comment: In both cases T is int, so I have to use "ToString<int>" in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Boost bind has some problems with function overloading.
You could of course by-pass the issue with function pointers.

```
void MetaData::test()
{
    boost::function< std::string() > foo;

    typedef std::string (*PFNToString)(int i);
    typedef std::string (*PFNToString2)(std::vector<int> const& vec);
    PFNToString pfn = &MetaData::ToString<int>;
    PFNToString2 pfn2 = &MetaData::ToString<int>;

    // Ok
    foo = boost::bind(pfn, boost::bind(&MetaData::getInt, this));
    std::cout << foo() << std::endl;

    // Compiler errors
    foo = boost::bind(pfn2, boost::bind(&MetaData::getIntVector, this));
    std::cout << foo() << std::endl;

    // Ok
    std::cout << ToString<int>(getIntVector()) << std::endl;
}
```

But since you want to use bind maybe you should consider changing the function name.