# How does std::endl not use any brackets if it is a function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, std

The question is pretty much in the title. According to [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/endl/), `std::endl` is actually a function. Looking at its declaration in `<iostream>`, this can be verified.

However, when you use `std::endl`, you don't use `std::endl()`. Instead, you use:

```
std::cout << "Foo" << std::endl;
```

In fact, if you use `std::endl()`, the compiler demands more parameters, as noted on the link above.

Would someone care to explain this? What is so special about `std::endl`? Can we implement functions that do not require any brackets when calling too?

Comment: Although not a duplicate question, the answers here answer your question: [4842901](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842901/c-statement-cannot-resolve-address-for-overloaded-function).

Comment: Thanks a lot for that link. It really fully explains it. :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`std::endl` is a function template declared (27.7.3.8):

```
template <class charT, class traits>
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& endl(basic_ostream<charT,traits>& os);
```

The reason that you can "stream" it to `std::cout` is that the `basic_ostream` class template has a member declared:

```
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<
    ( basic_ostream<charT,traits>& (*pf)(basic_ostream<charT,traits>&) );
```

which is defined to have the effect of returning `pf(*this)` (27.7.3.6.3).

`std::endl` without parentheses refers to a set of overload functions - all possible specializations of the function template, but used in a context where a function pointer of one particular type is acceptable (i.e. as an argument to `operator<<`), the correct specialization can be unambiguously deduced.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation! Is there a way of passing std::endl to a class, like in the following: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39019763/484230

Comment: For those wondering, yes, you can do `std::ostream & some_func(std::ostream &stream) { return stream << ":D"; }` and use it by doing `std::cout << some_func;`.

Answer (score 1):

`std::endl` is an object of some type (not really important) that is supplied as an argument to `operator<<( std::ostream &, decltype(std::endl))`.

### EDIT

Reading the other question would lead me to think that endl is a function template and that we most likely select the `ostream& operator<<(ostream&(*)(ostream&))` member function overload.

Comment: `std::endl` isn't an object (in the C++ sense), it's a function template.

Comment: ... which is why there's no `std::wendl`. I'm not sure if that's a good thing in hindsight.

Comment: @MSalters: I'm not sure how that's a reason.

Comment: @Tomalak : Well, there's `'\n'` and a distinct `L'\n'`. If you're thinking of `endl` as some object that's like `'\n'`, you'd expect a `wendl`.

Comment: @MSalters: I agree! Which is why I don't see how that `endl` is _able_ to be both is a reason that it _does_.

Answer (score 1):

Though it's a function [template], standard stream manipulators are designed to be sent to streams as function pointers (or functor object references). Inserting the result of a function call won't give you anything but the *value* that results from that function call.

This means that you stream the functor itself (`f`), rather than the result of calling it (`f()`).

Comment: **Note:** My phone really needs a backtick key.

Comment: `std::endl` isn't a class with an `operator()`; it's a function template.